# Strange errors in Visual C++ :: 'malloc' : function does not take 1 arguments

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

```
Error 38 error C2660: 'malloc' : function does not take 1 arguments C:\VolumeRenderer\render.cpp 296 1 VolumeRenderer
Error 39 error C2660: 'malloc' : function does not take 1 arguments C:\VolumeRenderer\render.cpp 412 1 VolumeRenderer
Error 40 error C2660: 'malloc' : function does not take 1 arguments C:\VolumeRenderer\render.cpp 414 1 VolumeRenderer
Error 41 error C2660: 'read_den' : function does not take 4 arguments C:\VolumeRenderer\render.cpp 506 1 VolumeRenderer
```

My all `malloc` sections are like this:

```
/* allocate space for the raw data */
density_size = BRAIN_XLEN * BRAIN_YLEN * BRAIN_ZLEN;
density = (unsigned char*)malloc(density_size);
if (density == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
  exit(1);
}
```

regarding `read_den` (last error) . `read_den` does take 4 parameters. You can see the function prototype & its corresponding call here:

```
  unsigned char *read_den(char *filename,int *xptr,int *yptr,int *zptr)// function prototype
  src_volume = read_den(src_file, &src_xlen, &src_ylen, &src_zlen);// function call
```

Is it my code or the errors that are absurd. How to rectify them?

**EDIT:**
can some one comment on the last error because. I'm unable to justify it.

**EDIT2:** When I changed the file extension from *.cpp to *.c then all errors are gone. So, I think it has something to do with C & C++.

Answer (score 3):

Wild guess: you used `malloc` incorrectly somewhere else, passing two arguments instead of one. This would result in an implicit declaration.

Try compiling with all warnings enabled and see if anything comes up.

---

Update: You could also put `#include <stlib.h>` as the very first line in your source file, so that any potential implicit declaration would be flagged as an error.

Comment: @Thomas : I enabled /Wall I got around 1600 warning. I did a quick search for 'malloc' in these warnings+errors and Other than the errors I mentioned in question. These are the other two entries that hit my search:

`Warning 841 warning C4514: '_MarkAllocaS' : unreferenced inline function has been removed C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\malloc.h 192 1 VolumeRenderer`
and `Warning 842 warning C4514: '_freea' : unreferenced inline function has been removed C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\malloc.h 227 1 VolumeRenderer`

Comment: 1600 warnings... maybe something to look into.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you shadow the real malloc function somewhere in your code. In gcc you can use the -Wshadow flag to test. I am sure there is something similiar in Visual Studio.

Edit: I read the second part you added and the errors seem to come indeed from incompatibilities between C and C++. Depending on the size of your project, this might be tedious work to sort out. I suggest, that you use the "extern" keyword to link your new C++ code to your working C code.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cplusplus_function(int a); 

main(){
    printf("c code\n");

    int* a = malloc(sizeof(int)); //just proving that this is indeed C code.
                                  //this would not compile with a C++ compiler

    cplusplus_function(5);
    return 0;
}
```

and a C++ function with the "extern" keyword:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" void cplusplus_function(int);

void cplusplus_function(int a){
    std::cout << "c++ code" << std::endl;
}
```

Now you can compile the files separately and link them together.

Comment: Shadowing is making something inaccessible by putting something above in its place so the former cannot be seen... You would probably have seen that expression while configuring your computer's BIOS ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you have `#include <stdlib.h>`?
2. Try generating the preprocessed output (with MSVC, this is done with the `/E` option).  Look through the resulting output for `malloc` and `read_den` declarations.